# Can't log in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: log

I have a problem that started just yesterday after using upgrade version of Ubuntu 14.04 since its release. Namely, all of a sudden, Ubuntu won't accept my password. I  changed it with passwd user, Ubuntu seemed to have accepted the new password, but yet again, it won't let me log in. It looks like Ubuntu is recognizing the password, starts the login process, but then it takes me back again to the welcome screen. Let me stress that I knew my password, that it was working properly and I had no problems whatsoever. I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu 14.04 and Xubuntu 14.04, so luckily, all my Ubuntu files are accessible from Xubuntu.
Any suggestions? Thanks